# What's an appropriate data model for tracking daily logging in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, data-modeling

I'm trying to decide on a relatively flat data model for a fitness track app. For a given day, a user would be able to enter 1) their workout time, 2) amount of snacks eaten, and 3) a binary toggle against a monthly challenge. A spreadsheet representation would be something like this:

[image: fitness log]

There would be several teams with five to six people each. A user would be able to view cumulative Team scores on main dashboard, and see a complete breakdown of entered points on their Team dashboard (which is basically a  view of this spreadsheet or something similar).

New team members can be added, and every month an existing user is put on an new team.

Obviously I need a "users" table. I'm not sure the best way to store the logs though. Would there be a main "dates" table or perhaps a "team" table? Or both?

**Team Table**

```
{
  "team1": {
    "entry1": {
      "user": "user1",
      "exercise": 1,
      "snacks": 2,
      "outside": false,
      "date": "6/1"
    },
    "entry2": {
      "user": "user2",
      "exercise": 4,
      "snacks": 0,
      "outside": false,
      "date": "6/1"
    },
    "entry3": {
      "user": "user2",
      "exercise": 1.5,
      "snacks": 1,
      "outside": true,
      "date": "6/3"
    },
    "entry4": {
      "user": "user1",
      "exercise": 1,
      "snacks": 1,
      "outside": true,
      "date": "6/2"
    }
  }
}
```

**Date Table**

```
{
  "6-1-18": {
    "entry1": {
      "user": "user1",
      "exercise": 1,
      "snacks": 2,
      "outside": false,
    },
    "entry2": {
      "user": "user2",
      "exercise": 4,
      "snacks": 0,
      "outside": false,
    },
    "entry3": {
      "user": "user3",
      "exercise": 1.5,
      "snacks": 1,
      "outside": true,
    },
    "entry4": {
      "user": "user4",
      "exercise": 1,
      "snacks": 1,
      "outside": true,
    }
  }
}
```

Or something completely different?

Comment: Data modeling for nosql type database should always follow from the queries you expect to perform.  If a model satisfies your queries the way you want, then it's good.  If it doesn't satisfy the queries, then it's no good.  You should think carefully about your queries and model the data accordingly.  In the absence of queries, all you can do is guess at what's going to work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not sure about the queries that you will have to run, then the best approach, also in a "NoSQL" DB, is using a normalized data model, which you get automatically from an ER or corresponding UML class diagram.

In a class diagram, you would have three classes: `Team`, `User` and `UserFitnessDay`. There would be a many-to-one association between `User` and `Team`, which is turned into a `team` reference property in a `User` class or a corresponding foreign key column (or ID reference attribute) `team_id`. There would also be an inseparable composition between `User` and `UserFitnessDay`, such that an instance of `UserFitnessDay` is a lifecycle-dependent component of a specific `User`. In such a composition, the table that corresponds to the component class (`UserFitnessDay`) has a composite primary key `(user_id, date)` where one attribute (`user_id`) is a foreign key referencing the table corresponding to the composite class (`User`).

I think you could use the following data model:

```
Team( id, name)
User( id, name, team_id FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Team)
UserFitnessDay( 
  user_id FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES User CASCADE DELETE, 
  date, 
  nmrOfExercises, 
  nmrOfSnacks, 
  hasBeenOutside,
  PRIMARY KEY( user_id, date)
)
```

Even if Firebase does not support foreign keys, you need to deal with their logic in your app code. Therefore, it helps to use an RDB-like schema.